# What should we use variable or assign property...objective c

Tags: objective-c, variables, ios7, properties

Is it recommended to use assign property or variables? For example :

```
@property(assing,nonatomic)int num;
```

or declare the int variable at the implementation :

```
@implementaion {
int num;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want to expose things to other objects (i.e. other view controllers or things that touch this object), you can use "`@property`".

If you want the data to stay internal to the object, use an ivar.

Obviously my answer is greatly simplified, but `@property` also comes with extra goodness like ARC (retaining the object or doing [atomic vs. non-atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/whats-the-difference-between-the-atomic-and-nonatomic-attributes)).  In my own code, I'm using @property more and more and ivars less and less.

Comment: +1 I agree that public interfaces should be declared as properties in the .h. But I wouldn't want future readers to infer that if it's private, you wouldn't want to use a property. It's just that you'd define private properties in the class extension in the .m file. I'd suggest that ivars are best reserved for private variables for which you don't need/want all the `@property` "goodness" (KVC, atomic/nonatomic, simplified memory semantics, etc.). Personally, I use properties (both public and private) almost exclusively now, but if one wants to use ivars for private variables, you can do that.